# Dart file running with flutter in vs code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, compilation

when gonna run dart code in vs code, is running with flutter and take so much time, how can fix this problem?
[image]

Comment: How is your 'run' configuration? Do you have the dart extension installed?

Comment: sure, i have Dart, Flutter and code runner extensions and right now i try "Dart filename.dart" and it runs the same way again

Comment: @Behnaaam Do you have any dependencies in your `pubspec.yaml` to git based repositories?

Comment: i'm not have any pubspec.yaml file in my directory, this problem is weird

Comment: Are you on a work computer behind a corporate firewall ?

Comment: I suspect that VSCode is using the Flutter's run parameters when it should be using Dart's run parameters. Try creating a new run config and see if it helps.

Comment: no it's just personal computer, i try this way but it not working, i install dart in from flutter framework, this can be problem?

Comment: Let's try a couple of things. Firstly, does $ dart your_code.dart work?

Comment: Thanks everyone I preferred to remove the flutter completely and just install the dart alone and the problem is now solved, thank you again